# Question about a proof of the fact that $n$ linearly independent vectors form a basis of $n$ dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space. Then any linearly independent set of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$.

Proof:

> Suppose $B =\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ do not span $V$. Then there's $w \in V$ s.t. $\displaystyle{w = \sum_{i = 1}^nk_iv_i + k_{n + 1}v_{n+ 1}}$. Now $C = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n, v_{n + 1}\}$ is linearly dependent and so we can write $w_{n +  1}$ in terms of preceding vectors: $\displaystyle{v_{n + 1} = \sum_{i = 1}^nc_iv_i}$. Thus $\displaystyle{w = \sum_{i = 1}^nk_iv_i + k_{n + 1}\sum_{i = 1}^nc_iv_i = \sum_{i = 1}^n(k_i + k_{n + 1}c_i)v_i}$ meaning $B$ spans $V$.

I have a question about the dependence of $C$. Suppose $B$ spans $V$. Then since $v_{n + 1} \in V,$ we have that $\displaystyle{v_{n + 1} = \sum_{i = 1}^nk_iv_i}$ meaning $\displaystyle{\sum_{i = 1}^nk_iv_i + (-1)v_{n + 1}} = \vec0$ which implies $C$ is linearly dependent. In other words, for $C$ to be linearly dependent, we want $B$ to span $V$. So how do they get $C$ to be dependent in the proof above?

Comment: What is $v_{n+1}$ supposed to be? It is never defined. Where did you see this proof?

Comment: @m_t_ Let $B$ span $V$. If $w \in V$, then $w = k_1v_1 + k_2v_2 + \ldots + k_nv_n.$ But $w = k_1v_1 + k_2v_2 + \ldots + k_nv_n + k_{n + 1}v_{n+1}$ would mean $w \not \in \text{span}(B)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes back to the definition of dimension of a vector space.

When we say the space in n dimensional, we mean that every set of linearly  independent vectors have at most $n$ elements.

Now if you have $n+1$ vectors one of  them is a linear combination of others.

Comment: @ Mohammad Riazi-Kermani If a vector space $V$ is $n$ dimensional and $v_i \in V,$ then by definition of basis, $v_i$ must span $V$. It seems like we always need span? In the given proof, they seem to want us to pretend $B$ doesn't span $V$ and before we reach any contradiction, use the fact that $B$ spans $V$. No inconsistency here?

Comment: There is no inconsistency in the proof. They say if you have $n$ linearly independent vectors in an $n$ dimensional space, then these vectors span the space therefore they constitute a basis for the space.

Comment: The proof says that $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n $ do not span $V$. So  if $v_{n + 1} \in V,$ then $v_{n + 1} \ne k_1v_1 + k_2v_2 + \ldots + k_nv_n.$

Comment: They assume  $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ do not span  V, then they come up with a contradiction which is $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ span V.

Comment: They assume $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ do not span $V$, then derive $v_{n+1} = c_1v_1 + \ldots + c_nv_n.$  But we know if  $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ do not span $V$, then $v_{n+1} \ne c_1v_1 + \ldots + c_nv_n$ if $v_{n+1} \in V.$ This occurs before the final contradiction.

Comment: I don't agree with the second line. When we say the space in $n$ dimensional, we _mean_ that every basis of the space has $n$ vectors. To get your statement from that, one could invoke the incomplete basis theorem. So the fact is implied, but it is not the meaning of "having dimension $n$".